# Problemas con margin-top

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un `h3` y le quiero dar `margin-top`, pero solamente me funciona si pongo un tamaño mayor a 500px. Si yo bajo el valor a 499, no funciona y queda sin margen. El `div` que necesito `margin` es el que dice "Inicio div noticias", el que tiene fondo amarillo.

La primera imagen es con 500px, y la segunda es con 400px:

[image: Imagen con 500PX margin-top]

[image: Imagen con 400px margin-top]

Éste es mi código:

```css
/*XS*/
/* All Mobile Sizes (devices and browser) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  

  .aux
  {
background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }

  .fch_button
  {
border-top: solid 1px #BDBDBD;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
  }


  .carousel 
{ 
  background-color: black;
}
  .margin30m
{
  margin-top: 30px;
}

  .imacrsl 
{
  /*height: 250px;*/
  max-height: 250px;
}


.redess
{
  display: none;
}

.toleft
{
  text-align: left;
}

.margintabla div
{
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.carousel-caption 
{
  background-color: unset;
  width:100%;
  margin-left:-15%;
  height: 20px;
  max-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.img-rounded
{
  font-size: 16px;
  border-radius: 0;
  color:white;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); 
  -moz-transform: rotate(-5deg);
}    
}


/*COL-SM*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  .aux
  {
background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }

  .fch_button
  {
border-top: solid 1px #BDBDBD;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .resumen_titulo
  {
min-height: 80px;
  }
  .img_min
  {
display: inline-block; 
width: auto;
max-height: 180px;
text-align: center;
  }

  .carousel-caption {
background-color: black;
width:100%;
margin-left:-20%;
opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .modal-xl {
  width: 86%;
  max-width:86%;
  }  
  .imacrsl {
width: auto;
height: 430px;
max-height: 430px;
  }
.carousel-inner { 
text-align: center;
  }

  .carousel 
  { 
background-color: black;
  }
}

/*COL-MD*/
  @media only screen and  (min-width: 992px){
  .aux
  {
background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }

  .fch_button
  {
border-top: solid 1px #BDBDBD;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .resumen_titulo
  {
min-height: 80px;
  }
  .img_min
  {
display: inline-block; 
width: auto;
max-height: 140px;
text-align: center;
  }

  .carousel-caption {
background-color: black;
width:100%;
margin-left:-20%;
opacity: 0.7;
  }


  .imacrsl {
width: auto;
max-height: 430px;
  }
  .carousel-inner { 
text-align: center;
  }

  .carousel 
  { 
background-color: black;
  }
}


/*COL-LG*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  .carousel-caption {
background-color: black;
width:100%;
margin-left:-20%;
opacity: 0.7;
  }

  .modal-xl {
  width: 86%;
  max-width:86%;
  }  
  .imacrsl {
width: auto;
height: 430px;
max-height: 430px;
  }
.carousel-inner { 
text-align: center;
  }

  .carousel 
  { 
background-color: black;
  }

  .img_min
  {
display: inline-block; 
width: auto;
max-height: 160px;
text-align: center;
  }

  .margin30m
  {
margin-top: 30px;
  }

  
  .aux
  {
background-color: #F2F2F2;
  }

  .fch_button
  {
border-top: solid 1px #BDBDBD;
padding-top: 25px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .resumen_titulo
  {
min-height: 80px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
  <!--inicio div seccion 1-->
  <div class="">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide col-md-12" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
      </ol>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div id="divres" class="carousel-inner peopleCarouselImg" role="listbox">
      </div>
      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Siguiente</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <!--fin div carousel-->
  </div>
  <!--inicio div noticias-Este div necesito MRGIN-TOP-->
  <div style="background-color: yellow;margin-top:500px;" class="">
    <h3>Noticias</h3>
    <div id="div_not" class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--fin div noticias-->
</div>
<!--fin div 1 seccion-->
```

Comment: Puedes añadir el css que estás usando'?

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez añadido.

Comment: Por lo que veo no tienes ningún `h3` en tu css, por lo que puede ser que dado el tamaño del contenedor no quepa y lo omita, prueba a ponerlo fuera del contenedor

Comment: @AlbertoMartínez lo hice, pero tampoco toma el margin

Comment: El código que compartes parece verse bien y no tener problemas con 500px o 400px. ¿Seguro que has incluido todo el código relevante? ¿Puede que haya más CSS que afecte a tu página?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro agregué el CSS completo. Como medida temporal, agregué una etiqueta h3 oculta para dar margin.